# Json encode array with php - array() becomes "Array{...}" not "[...]"

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to encode a response array as json and it has worked until now.

```
$response = array();
$response['icons']= $icons_arr;
$response['message']= $msg;

echo json_encode( $response );
```

The result is

```
Array{"icons":["{\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"icon_web_id\": \t\t\t\"0 ...
```

Javascript throws an error as it can't parse the "Array" word. I suspect the JQuery function $.parseJSON() expects a {} or a [].

What am I doing wrong here? Why won't json_encode() function properly?

Bonus question: what is causing all these \t\t\t\t's to occur?

Comment: I can't answer your entire problem, but `\t` is a tab in PHP. Maybe your code contains tabs instead of spaces somewhere.

Comment: Correct - previously I had a custom json encoding function to encode a nested object. It contained tabs and new rows. I removed it and all \n\t\t's dissapeard.

Comment: Great, now hopefully a full solution will come about.

Comment: Maybe make my suggestion as a partial answer? lol - no biggie, I'm not in this for points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other piece of code is producing the 'Array' output before the json string is output, you can prove this by changing the output line to

```
echo "json_encode returned ".json_encode( $response );
```

Check your code for other echo statements.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your **Bonus question**:

The `\t` is a tab in PHP. Your code may contain tabs instead of spaces somewhere, which could be rendered as multiple `\t`'s.